# Guardar datos en un fichero .txt

Tags: python

Tengo 2 archivos .csv, uno llamado "cities.csv" donde la información aparece tal que así:

```
GA,Butts,Jackson
GA,Butts,Jenkinsburg
GA,Calhoun,Arlington
```

Y otro llamado "states.csv" que la informaciñon aparece así:

```
AA,Armed Forces America
AE,Armed Forces
AK,Alaska
```

Utilizando python debo crear un nuevo fichero .txt que incluya la información así:

```
NH, New Hampshire: 10, 252
NJ, New Jersey: 21, 580
NM, New Mexico: 33, 350
```

Aparece la acortación del estado, nombre del estado: número de condados (en "cities.csv" las veces que aparece el nombre del medio), número de ciudades (las veces que se repite la acortación)

Para crear dicho texto.txt, tengo el siguiente trocito de programación:

```
    fichero = open(str(input("\nIntroduce el nombre del fichero: ")), "w")
    fichero.write()
    fichero.close()
```

Gracias a vuestra ayuda he conseguido contar las ciudades mediante un input:

```
estado = str(input("Introduce un estado: ")).capitalize()
    with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        for acortacion, state in reader:
            if state == estado:
                break
        else:
            print("No existe ese estado, vuelve a intentarlo")
            return
    with open('cities.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        total = 0
        buscar = False
        for state, *_ in reader:
            if state == acortacion:
                total += 1
                buscar = True
            else:
                if buscar:
                    break 
        print("\nHay " + str(total) + " ciudades en "+ str(estado))
```

Y listar los estados en la consola:

```
    with open('states.csv', newline="") as states:  
        lector = csv.reader(states)
        strA = ""
        for fila in lector:
            for i in range(len(fila) - 1):
                strA += fila[i] + ": "
            strA += fila[-1] + "\n\n"
        print(strA)
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como imprimir los datos en el fichero, conozco la opción de crear el fichero, y tengo las funciones para cada cosa, pero no sé juntarlo para que en el fichero .txt aparezca toda esa información por cada estado. Imagino que habrá que crear una serie de variable por cada apartado de cada línea del texto, y posteriormente utilizar un **for** para imprimirlo en el fichero .txt. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo todo en una sola iteración sobre cada archivo, yo recurriría a un diccionario de la forma:

```
{acortado-> str: {"estado": str, "condados": set(str), "ciudades": int}}
```

La idea es aprovecharse de que en los diccionarios y conjuntos no puede haber duplicados.

Ejemplo de datos de partida:

> **`states.csv`**
>
> ```
> AK,Alaska
> AL,Alabama
> ```
>
> **`cities.csv`**
>
> ```
> AK,Yukon Koyukuk,Tanana
> AK,Yukon Koyukuk,Venetie
> AK,Ketchikan Gateway,Ketchikan
> AK,Ketchikan Gateway,Saxman
> AL,Autauga,Autaugaville
> AL,Autauga,Billingsley
> AL,Autauga,Booth
> ```

```
import csv


estados = {}
with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    estados = {acortacion: {"estado": estado, "condados": set(), "ciudades": 0}
               for acortacion, estado in reader}
```

En éste punto tendremos ya un diccionario con la estructura descrita, con los campos `condados` y `ciudades` inicializados solamente a la espera de recorrer `cities`:

> ```
> {'AK': {'estado': 'Alaska', 'condados': set(), 'ciudades': 0},
>  'AL': {'estado': 'Alabama', 'condados': set(), 'ciudades': 0}
>  }
> ```

```
with open('cities.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for acortacion, condado, ciudad in reader:
        estados[acortacion]["condados"].add(condado)
        estados[acortacion]["ciudades"] += 1
```

En éste punto tenemos nuestro diccionario completo con todo lo que necesitamos:

> ```
> {'AK': {'estado': 'Alaska', 
>         'condados': {'Yukon Koyukuk', 'Ketchikan Gateway'},
>         'ciudades': 4},
>  'AL': {'estado': 'Alabama',
>         'condados': {'Autauga'},
>         'ciudades': 3}
>  }
> ```

solo queda formatear cada línea y escribir el txt de salida:

```
with open('output.txt', "w") as out_file:
    out_file.writelines(
        ((f"{acortacion}, {datos['estado']}: "
          f"{len(datos['condados'])}, {datos['ciudades']}\n")
             for acortacion, datos in estados.items()
             )
        )
```

Salida:

> **`output.txt`**
>
> ```
> AK, Alaska: 2, 4
> AL, Alabama: 1, 3
> ```

P.D si alguien de Alaska ve ésto (lo dudo...) que no se ofenda por llamar "condados" a los Boroughs... :)

Answer (score 1):

Para escribir en un fichero tienes que hacer prácticamente lo mismo que para leer:

```
nms = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

with open('fichero.csv', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in nms:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

`writerow` es un método que escribe una fila de datos.

El **output** sería:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Para mas información: http://zetcode.com/python/csv/